# Automatic startup of Samba service in Docker containers

Tags: samba, startup, systemd, docker, container

I have a Raspberry on which docker is running. I created an Ubuntu container (current version) on which I installed Samba.

Samba works fine, I start it and my pcs access the shares.

I then set the Docker container to start automatically along with the raspberry, and via systemd I enabled the smbd service of samba.

But when the container starts the smbd service does not start, I always have to start it by hand

This is the result of `systemctl status smbd`

```
smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service, enabled)
    Active: failed (failed)
```

Comment: There are some things in your post that doesn't make sense to me. 1) Docker containers and their services start automatically, so no need to do anything special. 2) Docker containers don't use `systemd` by default. 3) I fail to see the purpose of running Samba inside a Docker container. To me, your question raises even more questions... 